# BigInteger datatype like in iOS

Tags: ios, biginteger

is there any datatype like BigInteger in objective-c. Please don't share libraries, I have tired from those all libraries.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in BigInteger type in Objective-C. If you don't want a third party library (like GMP) you're out of luck.